# Sufficient conditions for the Schroder functional equation

Tags: real-analysis, functions, functional-equations

Let $f: (0,1)\rightarrow (0,1)$ be a given  function. A real function $\phi:(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is said to satisfy the **Schroder functional  equation**, with parameter $s\neq 0, 1$, if
$$\phi(f(x))=s\phi(x), \ \ \forall x\in (0,1).$$

I am particularly interested in the case where $s=2$ and on what conditions one must impose on $f$ so that there exists a nonzero continuous solution $\phi$ of the corresponding equation. According to *"Kuczma - Functional equations in a single variable"*, pg. 136,  if $f$ belongs in $R_\xi^0$, then there **do not** exist nonzero continuous solutions. The set $R_\xi^0$ contains the strictly increasing continuous functions with the property that $f(x)>x$ in $(0,\xi)$ and $f(x)<x$ in $(\xi, 1)$, where $\xi$ is the fixed point of $f$.

So this gives us  a necessary condition that $f$ needs to satisfy so that the Schroder's equation  has a  nonzero solution. But is there a   sufficient condition? In particular,  if $f$ is a strictly increasing function satisfying $f(x)<x$ in $(0,\xi)$ and $f(x)>x$ in $(\xi, 1)$, is it true that the corresponding equation 
$$\phi(f(x))=2\phi(x),$$
always has a nonzero continuous solution?

Comment: Don't have that one, I have Iterative Functional Equations by Kuczma, Choczewski and Ger(1990). Probably in here somewhere, but it takes some time to interpret. First I will see if I can find your nonexistence result.

Comment: requested your book from library, there now, see what is meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, got the book. It appears the main thing you missed is the freedom to consider $f^{-1}$ instead of $f.$  So, for example, in Theorem 6.1 on page 137, let $h(x) = f^{-1}(x)$ so that $h \in R^0_0.$ For now, demand $h$ to be $C^2.$ then we can solve
$$ \psi(h(t)) = \frac{1}{2} \psi(t),  $$
with $\psi'(0)$ whatever you prefer.
Taking $t = f(x)$ gives
$$  \psi(x) = \frac{1}{2} \psi(f(x)),$$
$$  2\psi(x) =  \psi(f(x)).$$